# Vuetify: How to set v-data-table row height manually?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to set `<v-data-table>` row height manually ?

Setting the table to `dense` is some small enough for my needs.

By default, [`$data-table-dense-row-height`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#sass) is set to `32px !default;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70697036-bo4yx?file=/src/components/TableExample.vue

If you don't want to mess with SASS variables, or modify the value globally you can use the `item-class` prop of the `v-data-table` like this:

```html
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="desserts"
   :items-per-page="5"
   class="elevation-1"
   :item-class="setRowStyle"
>
</v-data-table>
```

You need to define a function to be able to apply css to the hole item row.

```js
methods: {
   setRowStyle(item) {
      /* Here you can also do some validation
      in case you want to apply different css 
      classes depending on item attributes 
      values */
      return 'style-1'
   }
}
```

And then you simply defined the css you want to be apply to your data-table rows:

```css
<style>
   .style-1 td {
      height: 100px !important;
   }
</style>
```

If you want to use a `scoped` css style block, you'll need to defined your css using deep selector to properly apply the height to td tags.

```css
<style scoped>
   >>>.style-1 td {
      height: 100px !important;
   }
</style>
```

If you also want to modify the row headers height, you can use the `class` attribute in your headers array.